# Conversion List<List<String>> to MutableList<List<String>> crashes sometime?

Tags: kotlin

In my app I have a List<List>. It's a list of radiostation. Each radiostation is a list with the information for that station, e.g. name, slogan, stream url, ...

In the app there's a "dice" to let the app play a random radiostation.

In the search function the "dice" is shown. In my search code I check if the "dice" (dobbelsteen in Dutch) is not present and if the List is not empty. If there's no "dice" I add the dice. But I have some crashes reported in Google Play Console.

```
if (dobbelsteen !in categorieIsSelected && categorieIsSelected.isNotEmpty()) {
        
   (categorieIsSelected as MutableList<List<String>>).add(0, dobbelsteen)
    
}
```

I'm not able to reproduce the error. And most of the time it works fine for the most users. I think somehow the List<List> conversion to MutableList<List> crashes. I'm not sure.

Does anyone have any clue what can be the problem here?

Update - See the error message in Google Play Console:

```
Exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
  at java.util.AbstractList.add (AbstractList.java:153)
  at com.familiekoning.radionedplus.RadiostationsAdapter$getFilter$1.publishResults (RadiostationsAdapter.kt:725)
  at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage (Filter.java:284)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8741)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:571)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1067)
```

See also the complete function. It's used to search in a List with radiostations:

```
override fun getFilter(): Filter = object : Filter() {

        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence): FilterResults {

            var filteredList: MutableList<List<String>> = ArrayList(ArrayList())

            if (constraint.isEmpty()) {

                filteredList = categorieWasSelected as MutableList<List<String>>

            } else {

                val filterPattern = constraint.toString().lowercase(Locale.ROOT).trim { it <= ' ' }

                if (exampleListFull != null) {

                    for (item in categorieWasSelected) {

                        if (item[0].lowercase(Locale.ROOT).contains(filterPattern)) {

                            filteredList.add(item)

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            val results = FilterResults()

            results.values = filteredList
            results.count = filteredList.count()

            return results

        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence, results: FilterResults) {
            
            if (results.count > 0 && zoeken) {

                categorieIsSelected = results.values as MutableList<List<String>>

                //check of dobbelsteen erin zit bij zoekresultaat. Nee, dan toevoegen.
                if (dobbelsteen !in categorieIsSelected && categorieIsSelected.isNotEmpty()) {

                    //KT.725 geeft error is nu 726
                    (categorieIsSelected as MutableList<List<String>>).add(0, dobbelsteen)

                }

                //check of dobbelsteen als enige over is.
                if (dobbelsteen in categorieIsSelected && categorieIsSelected.size == 1) {

                    (categorieIsSelected as MutableList<List<String>>).clear()

                }

                notifyDataSetChanged()

            } else {

                categorieIsSelected = emptyList()

                notifyDataSetChanged()

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: You're going to have to at least post some error info otherwise we're just guessing too. But if (for whatever reason) `categorieIsSelected` *isn't* a `MutableList`, then calling `add` on it will crash, yeah (https://pl.kotl.in/KoMBpT1Jt). If you need a `MutableList` then you should be using that type anyway, unchecked casts like that are dangerous!

Comment: There is an important misconception in your question. `as` doesn't convert to `MutableList`. `categorieIsSelected` has to be a `MutableList` list in the first place for this to work, otherwise it will throw `ClassCastException`. I think the best solution is to make `categorieIsSelected` a `MutableList`, then you don't have to use `as`.

Comment: Thx, I posted the error in the original post.

Comment: Thx for clearing up that it's a cast not a convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`as` is not a conversion, it's a [cast](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator).** And (at the [risk](/a/61131112/10134209) [of](/a/52724331/10134209) [repeating](/a/54108139/10134209) [myself](/a/61183059/10134209)) **a cast doesn't convert a value to the required type; a cast promises the compiler that the value is *already* the required type**.

To convert it, the simplest way is to call [`toMutableList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-mutable-list.html) on it. (Most conversion methods are called `to<Type>()`.)

However, that's not very efficient, as it *always* creates a new MutableList, even if it's *already* one. If that matters, you could use the [`as?`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/typecasts.html#safe-nullable-cast-operator) safe-cast operator to check first:

```
val mutableList = categorieIsSelected as? MutableList<List<String>>
                ?: categorieIsSelected.toMutableList()
```

If the value is not the required type, `as?` gives null, which the [`?:`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/null-safety.html#elvis-operator) elvis operator then substitutes. Either way, the rest of the code would need to use that `mutableList`.

(However, as comments have already pointed out, you wouldn't need to do any of this if you already had a `MutableList` to start with! So if that's possible, it'd be the simplest solution overall.)

---

If the value is *not* already the required type, casting usually gives a runtime error such as a `ClassCastException`.

However, this particular case is an unusual one, because on Kotlin/JVM both `List` and `MutableList` are compiled to the same Java interface (as the Java standard library doesn't distinguish between mutable and immutable lists). So on Kotlin/JVM, if you have any `List` implementation, you can *always* cast it to `MutableList`!

So, if the code in the question was run on some other platform, the cast might give an exception — but on Kotlin/JVM, it would actually succeed. Instead, it would go on to call `add()`, which would probably throw an `UnsupportedOperationException` if the list isn't actually mutable.

(We can't tell which is the case here, as the question doesn't provide the actual error message…)